# Изображение не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки

Tags: gd, php

Приветствую всех.

Такой вот парадокс, на FireFox выскакивает данная ошибка. Изображение должно просто сохраняться после генерации. (Да, работает), в других браузерах показывает просто пустое окно. Но, на firefox такая вот штука, с чем это связано? (Ради интереса, хочется узнать, почему так)

Comment: Телепаты сегодня в отгуле. Такой вот парадокс.

Comment: каждый браузер борется с ошибками по своему. Разработчики FireFox решили вот так вот.